# WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK hook in C#

Tags: c#, interop, hook

I am trying to create a callback for "WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK" hook in C#. This is the code

```
private delegate IntPtr JournalPlaybackProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private static IntPtr JournalPlaybackCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
        if (HC_GETNEXT == nCode && curr < EventMsgs.Count)
        {
            EVENTMSG hookStruct = (EVENTMSG)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(EVENTMSG));
            EVENTMSG currentMsg = EventMsgs[curr];
            hookStruct.message = currentMsg.message;
            hookStruct.paramL = currentMsg.paramL;
            hookStruct.paramH = currentMsg.paramH;
            hookStruct.hwnd = currentMsg.hwnd;
            hookStruct.time = currentMsg.time;
        }
        if (HC_SKIP == nCode)
        {
            curr++;
        }
        if (curr == EventMsgs.Count)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_journalPlaybackProcHookID);
            _journalPlaybackProcHookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_journalPlaybackProcHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I get the callback correctly, i suppose i need to modify the value of lParam with my data to playback the events. How do i do this?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I can record the values just fine, but the playback is proving troublesome. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to

Marshal.StructureToPtr(hookStruct,lParam,true);

To write it back at some point. When I run it just hangs though.